# Is there a way to set variables inside an If condition in Robot Framework?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, robotframework

I've tried this to increment the variable after, but it didn't work

```
Run Keyword If    '${state}'=='True'    Run Keywords    Click Element 
   xpath=//button[@overflow]  
...    AND Click Element    css=#stack  
...    ${i} Set Variable    1  
...    AND FOR ${item} IN ${items}  
            Log    ${item}
            Log    ${i}
            ${i}    Set Variable    ${i} + 1
           END
```

Comment: because that block of code is part of a Keyword and it would be weird for a Keyword calling another no?

Comment: If you want to run a for loop inside an if, you do not have much other options. I think it is fine to have more keywords for sub-steps, especially if that makes the test more readable. You could implement the whole keyword in Python as a library where you can do such logic structures in a single function aka keyword.

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the `Run Keywords` and replace it with a user keyword in which you can use `FOR` loop and you could increment your variable like `${i}    Evaluate    ${i}+1`.
You could also return `${i}` or anything else and use its value in the test later on.

```
*** Test Cases ***
Test
    ${i}=    Run Keyword If    'True'=='True'    My logic
    Log    ${i}

*** Keyword ***
My Logic
    Log     xpath=//button[@overflow]  
    Log     css=#stack  
    ${i}    Set Variable    1
    FOR    ${item}    IN   item1    item2
        Log    ${item}
        Log    ${i}
        ${i}    Evaluate    ${i}+1
    END
    [Return]    ${i}
```